# WordPress - wp_insert_post не устанавливает категории

Tags: php, wordpress

Имею следующую проблему - функция wp_insert_post игнорирует указание категории.
Пробую так:

```
    $post_data = array(
                'post_title' => $t['title'],
                'post_content' => $t['text'],
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'post_author' => 1,
                'post_category' => array($t['category']),
                'tax_input' => array('category' => $t['category'])
            );
$post_id = wp_insert_post($post_data);
```

Пост добавляется, всё ок, но вот категория не устанавливается. Сверялся с [документацией](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/) , но ничего внятного нет. Категория всё равно не устанавливается.

Не подскажете, в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0):

> Не подскажете, в чем может быть проблема?

Проверяй что приходит в `$t['category']`. Там должны быть ID.

```
'post_category' => array( 8,39 )
```